# Symfony2: get list of all routes with their controller

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, command

I want to get all routes with their controller, I know this command

**php app/console debug:router**

But that shows only the routes not their controller.

Is there any way to get list of routes and thir controllers ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If the CLI command is fine for you, there is an option to add a controller

```
php app/console debug:router --show-controllers
```

You can of course then grep if you search for something specific.
You can check other options (not much really) by running

```
php app/console debug:router --help
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is valid only if you have an unique prefix per controller

```
controller_1:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/Controller_1"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /controller_1

controller_2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/Controller_2"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /controller_2
```

Now you can do

**php app/console debug:router | grep "my_prefix"** (for example controller_1)